# Everyone group doesn't include all my users from AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user, user-accounts

I have a problem I've added everyone to the Visitors group and some people can see the site other cannot unless I add them as contributors, which i shouldn't i know. And yes my User Profile Synchronization is working yes it's synced. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had same issue and as per our analysis we came to know that this is a LogonTokenService cache issue. We followed below steps in order to know.

- Did full user profile synch
- Wait for 24 hours to cache expiry
- The user login worked automatically

Some articles suggesting to reset the Logon token expiration time but we didn`t do that

    `$s=Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
    $s.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -hour 1)
    $stsc.Update()
    iisreset /noforce`